# Cannot update a component (`X) while rendering a different component (`Y`)

Tags: reactjs

I have a code that works fine but throws a warning in the console. I have searched for solutions and came across the solution which says that I should wrap my setState in useEffect but the problem is that it's a function. Here's the code from `<HonestTimePicker />` element that causes error.

[image]

```
    const handleTime = (type, value) => {
    setState((prev) => {
      prev[type] = value
      onChange && onChange(state.hours + ':' + state.minutes)
      return prev
    })
  }
```

My `<ShiftsModal/>` element has a `<HonestTimePickerInput />` as a child like a normal input.

Comment: Probably not related, but doing `prev[type] = value` is **bad**. You mustn't mutate a React state, you have to create a new object with that property modified (use `Object.assign` with a new target object, or object spread).

Comment: @FZs Thank you, I'll start using that from now on, can you tell me more why this is bad?

Comment: Because React state is meant to be immutable, and although React.js doesn't *enforce* that, it still *assumes* that. Modifying what's assumed to be immutable may mess with the inner workings of React in who knows what ways. Most notably, that can cause components to fail to rerender, because when React compares the new state with the current one, it'll find that they are the same (because mutation altered the current state too). Google "react state mutation" for more about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The issue is that my `onChange` was setting the state on parent component so I took it out of the function and put it in the new useEffect so it looks like this now:

```
  const handleTime = (type, value) => {
    setState((prev) => {
      let newObj = { ...prev }
      newObj[type] = value
      return newObj
    })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    onChange && onChange(state.hours + ':' + state.minutes)
  }, [state])
```